# Silverlight 3, updating text in a parent xaml layout from a xaml layout in a frame

Tags: silverlight, xaml, frame, parent

I have a main screen with a frame placed centrally which fills about half the screen when it is visible, a button pressed on the main screen makes the frame visible and populates it with another xaml file (lets call it frame layout)

What I would like to do is update a text box on the main screen when a button on the frame layout is pressed.

It would also be usefull if I could collapse the visibility of the frame from a button inside the frame.

Hoping anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to accomplish some master details scenario. 
Please check out those links so see if it points you to the right direction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight4trainingcourse_sl4lob_02_03_showingevents.aspx
http://www.devcurry.com/2011/02/silverlight-4-master-details-with-two.html

If this is not what you are looking for please provide more details and code example what you already got.

Hope that helps...